# mvc jquery autocomplete jquery-3.1.1.js error object do not support this property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using `MVC Bootstrap Jquery` App.

I have a `@Html.EditorFor` with `Autocomplete`.

On load got this error...

> jquery-3.1.1.js object do not support this property  'Autocomplete'

My View looks like this...

```html
<div class="DvCampoUp">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.upload.CityName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "StylelastNameNotOb100 Required",  placeholder = "Place", @id = "Place" } })
  </div>

   @section Scripts {

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        
   $(function () {
                $('#Place').autocomplete({        
                alert(1);
  });  
            });
```

My Layout looks like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
    
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    
<body class="LimpiarBody">
    <div id="Header">
        @Html.Action("Controller", "Method")
    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
        <footer>
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Footer.cshtml")
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/clientfeaturesscripts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I an using `Jquery-3.1.1`. In an older version i am using `Jquery-1.10.1` with the same View an Layout and it Works fine.

Why does not work with Jquery-3.1.1 version?

Have I forgot an include?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have to include

> jquery-ui.min.js